# Why are functional groups a part of hydrocarbons?

Tags: hydrocarbons

So, I was asked a very innocent question by my friend that all hydrocarbons are defined as compounds made up **entirely** of hydrogen and carbon(which can be confirmed by going to any educational site like Wikipedia, Brilliant, Khan academy etc.). But, everyone almost immediately *sort of* contradicts it by putting functional groups as a part of hydrocarbons.

So a few questions-

1. why are functional groups part of hydrocarbons, despite being different from hydrogen and carbon?
2. if 1. is answered successfully, then is the definition wrong for hydrocarbons?

P.S. me and my friends are 10 graders, so a language simple enough for us would be much appreciated.

Thanking in advance

Comment: "putting functional groups as a part of hydrocarbons" Who is the "everyone" who does this?

Comment: My coursebook, even khan academy groups hydrocarbons and functional groups

Comment: Can you provide links or photos of your book, etc.?

Comment: https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/jesc104.pdf

Comment: As far as I saw, that book does not make this claim. Even NCERT gets that one right.

Comment: That is a classic "even NCERT gets that one right"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrocarbon is an umbrella term for all compounds which contain carbon or hydrogen; benzene, methane, acetylene all are hydrocarbons. Yet you can attach words as sulfonated before the hydrocarbon(s) as a class of compounds such as a benzene sulfonic acid.

Hydrocarbons may have "hydrocarbon" functional groups such as the iso- before the common name, isobutane, isoctane etc. This is isooctane or in modern IUPAC nomenclature it is
2,2,4-Trimethylpentane. So you do have methyl groups in this hydrocarbon.

[image]